# Qual a melhor forma e mais segura de identificar um dispositivo no webservice?

Tags: android, web-service, ios, segurança, criptografia

Estou desenvolvendo um APP (no momento somente Android - Java puro), ele consumira um webservice feito em PHP (utilizo o mini Framework Silex).

Como sabemos hoje temos que proteger tudo ao máximo, então tomei algumas medidas de segurança:

1. Utilizarei HTTPS em todas requisições entre dispositivos e o
   webservice;
2. Cada dispositivo recebe pra si uma key única quando ele é aberto
   pela primeira vez, a key permite acesso e identifica o dispositivo
   no servidor.

Obs.: A key é armazenada tanto no servidor quanto no dispositivo do usuário e em qualquer requisição essa key é enviada para o servidor e o servidor verifica se é igual a que ele possuí.

Pretendo ainda implementar mais questões de segurança, como criptografar os dados antes de saírem dos dispositivos ou do webservice, e obviamente quando chegar no destino final vão ser descriptografados, claro cada dispositivo terá sua própria senha e o servidor possuíra todas as senhas. Isso eu ainda não sei como irei fazer então se alguém quiser dar algum concelho será bem-vindo. Outra coisa que farei é a ofuscação do código do APP.

Porém no momento o que me incomoda é as trocas de informações entre o servidor e os dispositivos, essa forma que estou trabalhando pra mim está muito superficial então gostaria de incrementar a segurança nas requisições. Porém não faço ideia de como realizar isso e venho pedir dicas da comunidade para eu poder melhorar minhas aplicações.

Comment: Recomendações são muito subjetivas. Se você já tem o web service tente pesquisar sobre "formas de autenticação de autorização em web services"

Comment: Faltam muitas informações na questão, inclua mais detalhes como qual tecnologia usou para o WebService. Vou colocar uma resposta mais informativa apenas para lhe dar um norte, mais é preciso elaborar melhor sua questão.

Comment: @Pagotti sim concordo porém estou numa seca de ideias sobre esse assunto que vim pedir qualquer ideia pra comunidade.

Comment: Com a atualização da pergunta ficou mais claro o que você está procurando. A sua preocupação sobre segurança do conteúdo, se já está usando HTTPS não vejo motivo para criptografar os dados. Na questão de autorização, se estiver usando token, da uma olhada no [JWT] (https://jwt.io/introduction/)

Comment: @Pagotti o HTTPS protege todas as informações da requisição? Pois se não proteger um atacante pode ter acesso aos dados necessário como o token, vou ver sobre esse JWT, obrigado

Comment: @MateusFMello HTTPS é uma camada se segurança em cima do HTTP. O browser troca informação criptografada com o servidor web. É claro que não é 100% seguro porque ele é baseado em certificados, ou seja, se tiverem acesso a sua chave pode ser quebrado, mas dai até mesmo uma criptografia própria que você fizer vai ter uma chave correndo o mesmo risco. Certificados também podem ter custos.

Answer (score 3):

O que você está procurando é um método de ***autenticação ou autorização*** para o seu WebService, mais isto varia de acordo com a tecnologia empreendida no desenvolvimento do seu WebService. Se você estiver utilizando WebServices SOAP ou WCF com .NET é uma abordagem, se estiver utilizando APIs REST a abordagem é outra. Entende como isso pode ser complexo?

Vou lhe passar algumas informações que poderão lhe dar um norte sobre o que pode ser feito, baseado em tecnologias .NET que são as que domíno. Visto também que você não explicou qual a tecnologia utilizou para desenvolver seu backend.

Basicamente autenticação com serviços Web envolvem o envio de algumas informações no cabeçalho da requisição e processamento destes dados no servidor, validando o usuário (dispositivo) ou não, o que deve gerar um erro [HTTP 401 - Unauthorized](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Existem bibliotecas e frameworks que ajudam a fazer isso em cada tecnologia, por exemplo em ASP.NET MVC tem o [ASP .NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity), o [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) que pode ser utilizado com Web API e também integra sua aplicação com redes sociais como Twitter e Facebook.

Dentro de cada abordagem, também existem inúmeras maneiras de se implementar autenticação.

Agora, se você quiser desenvolver tudo na mão, o que não é o ideal, você pode incluir um parâmetro nos métodos do WebService que pode servir de token de validação, e em cada você pode criar um método para validação deste token.

Não me orgulho disso, mais já fiz isso algumas vezes, abaixo o exemplo de um método que criei em um WCF:

```
public class WcfClientValidations : IWcfClientValidations
{
    DataContext context = new DataContext();


    public string GetData(string clientToken, int code)
    {
        TokenValidation(clientToken);

        return context.Data.Where(o => o.code = code).ToList();
    }

    private void TokenValidation(string clientToken)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientToken))
        {
            throw new Exception("Token inexistente !");
        }

        try
        {
            var clientCode = (int) Base64Decode(clientToken);
            var clientDb = context.Clients.Where(o => o.code = clientCode);

            if (clientDb == null)
              throw new Exception("Cliente inexistente ou token inválido !");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problemas ao validar o cliente !");
        }       
    }

    private static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
}
```

Como você pode ver no método GetData eu recebo um clientToken que é convertido e válidado retornando uma exceção caso o cliente não exista.

Espero ter ajudado, apesar de não ter muitas informações na pergunta.

Comment: Então estou fazendo algo parecido, estou utilizando php no webservice, dai eu fiz o seguinte, na primeira vez em que o usuário acessa o APP ele se conecta no webservice e solicita um token, o token é uma sha512 gerada a partir de algumas informações sobre o dispositivo que foram enviadas na requisição, essa hash é salva no dispositivo e no webservice e a cada nova requisição essa hash é verificada, dai é dada ou não a permissão pro dispositivo.